# jRuby Dir.glob not working with file.join

Tags: ruby

in Following code, metadata_files  not returning [] but there is lots of  file there, any idea/suggestion

here temp_dir is /tmp and METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION = .metadata so lot of .metadata file , nested inside /tmp

```
metadata_files = Dir.glob(File.join(temp_dir, "**" "*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between `"**"` and `"*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}"`, so the strings are getting combined too early (`"a" "b" == "ab"`)

here is your original code for building the path:

```
temp_dir = "/tmp"
METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION = ".metadata"
puts File.join(temp_dir, "**" "*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}")
# => /tmp/***.metadata
```

and fixed:

```
temp_dir = "/tmp"
METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION = ".metadata"
puts File.join(temp_dir, "**", "*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}")
# => /tmp/**/*.metadata
```