# Dir.glob stuck and thread not moving

Tags: ruby, jruby

Following code is stuck and it is not moving further in a custom plugin (here `temp_dir = /tmp`)

```
METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION = '.metadata'
metadata_files = Dir.glob(File.join(temp_dir, "**" ,"*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}"))
```

Comment: why did you post another question? I answered your identical one this morning ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jRuby Dir.glob not working with file.join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100353/jruby-dir-glob-not-working-with-file-join)

Comment: Because you've updated the question to include the fixes suggested in the answer here and in @maxpleaner's answer the duplicate question, it's no longer clear if this is still a question about a thread getting stuck or if it was just a syntax issue and a missing `File.join`. If it's resolved please consider accepting an answer, otherwise you may need to update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't valid Ruby, but assuming that's just a typo it looks like you need to use `File.join` first. Per the [Dir.glob docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob), `glob` needs multiple parts of the path to be `File.join`'d first. Something closer to this:

```rb
metadata_files_path = File.join(temp_dir, "**", "*#{METADATA_FILE_EXTENSION}")
metadata_files = Dir.glob(meta_data_files_path)
```

Comment: sorry, wrong copy paste... but this issue, I have already fix